# How to transform table in Pandas (rows to columns)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a dataframe in Pandas, which looks like this:

| metric | all_areas | area_1 | area_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| team_1_count | 30 | 31 | 31 |
| team_1_sum | 1146 | 536 | 308 |
| team_2_count | 38 | 38 | 41 |
| team_2_sum | 1146 | 536 | 308 |

I need to transform the table to be like this:

[image: desirable result]

is there any way to make it? Is it even possible in Pandas?
Example data is weird because it is fake and does not make sense.

Comment: `split` the metric columns in two (`df[['metric', 'col']] = df['metric'].str.rsplit('_', n=1, expand=True)`) and `pivot` or `unstack`.

Comment: @mozway can you please clarify a little? what does it mean to split the metric column? why?

Comment: You have many different ways to do this, here is one: `out = df.drop(columns='metric').join(df['metric'].str.rsplit('_', n=1, expand=True)).pivot(index=0, columns=1).rename_axis(index=None, columns=[None, None])` Please read the duplicate, read the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/reshaping.html), and search SO on `pivot`/`stack`/`unstack`, this is one of the most frequently asked pandas question.